# Worldpay Response Check MAC Value

Tags: php, xml, redirect, url-parameters, worldpay

I'm developing a small PHP application that allows users to pay on my website using the [worldpay hosted integration](https://developer.worldpay.com/docs/wpg/hostedintegration).

I'm using the worldpay test environment which is https://secure-test.worldpay.com/jsp/merchant/xml/paymentService.jsp I am also using the [test cards](http://support.worldpay.com/support/kb/bg/testandgolive/tgl5103.html).

I have form at `/index.php` on my website, when submitted it posts the form values (amount / cartId / currency / email / etc...) to `/xml.php` where I capture the values and insert them into my XML. Using cURL I send this XML to worldpay and then user is redirected to the worldpay payment page to complete the purchase. All working so far.

I have setup custom result URLs as described in [the docs](https://developer.worldpay.com/docs/wpg/hostedintegration/paymentpageintegration#custom-result-urls).

```
$successURL = urlencode( "/callback.php?paymentStatus=success");
$failureURL = urlencode( "/callback.php?paymentStatus=failure" );
$pendingURL = urlencode( "/callback.php?paymentStatus=pending" );
$errorURL = urlencode( "/callback.php?paymentStatus=error" );
```

In my `callback.php` I am checking `$_GET['paymentStatus']` and redirecting to `index.php` with a `$_SESSION['paymentStatus']`. Something like;

```
$paymentStatus = $_GET['paymentStatus'];

if( $_SESSION['paymentStatus'] = 'success'; ){
    header('Location: index.php');
    exit();
}
// etc
```

In my `index.php` I am checking `$_SESSION['paymentStatus']` and displaying a message accordingly.

All appears to be working so far during my testing, however I am confused about [securing payments with the MAC](https://developer.worldpay.com/docs/wpg/hostedintegration/securingpayments). I have been assigned a `MAC Secret` value by the worldpay admins but I'm not sure how I should be using this.

I understand I need to compare the MAC value sent in the response of worldpay with the MAC value I have been provided with in order to ensure it's genuine. The problem is I have no idea where to check for [their MAC response](https://developer.worldpay.com/docs/wpg/hostedintegration/paymentrequests#our-response)?

When I submit a (successful) payment in the test environment I am redirected back to my index page and my custom success message is displayed. When I look at the console and check the network tab I can see various files with response headers but none of them contain anything like their example;

> [https://www.mymerchant.com/Success.jsp?orderKey=MYADMINCODE^MYMERCHANT^T0211010&paymentStatus=AUTHORISED&paymentAmount=1400&paymentCurrency=GBP&mac2=fdbdbc16fbe8d8e56159fc332a5293e32b3d6aea61f10849da5c28819ff56711](https://www.mymerchant.com/Success.jsp?orderKey=MYADMINCODE%5EMYMERCHANT%5ET0211010&paymentStatus=AUTHORISED&paymentAmount=1400&paymentCurrency=GBP&mac2=fdbdbc16fbe8d8e56159fc332a5293e32b3d6aea61f10849da5c28819ff56711)

Some of the files I see in my network tab are;

```
https://hpp-sandbox.worldpay.com/app/hpp/62-0/payment/result?validInputs=true&ajax=true

https://example.com/callback.php?paymentStatus=success

ddc.html

index.php

process
```

According to [their docs](https://developer.worldpay.com/docs/wpg/hostedintegration/securingpayments);

> Worldpay's redirect message to the result URL contains a number of
> parameters that include:
>
> orderKey, paymentAmount, paymentCurrency, paymentStatus

I have added the following to my `callback.php`;

```
print_r($_GET);
die();
```

This is what I see;

```
Array ( [paymentStatus] => success )
```

Any ideas as to where I should be checking for these parameters? Would it be that I am using the test environment and not the live one, perhaps these values aren't sent in the test environment?

Their docs are kinda all over the place...

Comment: The mac is in the URL itself, as you've posted, in the `mac2` parameter. Parse that out, take the values for these parameters in this order (per their docs): `orderKey:paymentAmount:paymentCurrency:paymentStatus` and run [`hash_hmac`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.hash-hmac.php) on that

Comment: You should be checking all of this in `callback.php`

Comment: In your callback.php do a `print_r` on `$_GET` and then `die`, and you should see all of your parameters. You should be able to pull out the four parameters and then run your `hash_hmac`. I'm on a call right now so I can't write too much code, unfortunately

Comment: According to [this](https://developer.worldpay.com/docs/wpg/hostedintegration/paymentpageintegration#parameters-you-can-receive), you also need to go into their admin UI and turn on `Send URL parameters`